# Why Chrome seems requesting Javascript files asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html

Given that my HTML page requests 3 script files:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
<script src="c.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d.css"/>
```

Until now my understanding was that browser requests `a.js` and document is not parsed any further until `a.js` is downloaded and executed (default behaviour without async attribute on script tag).

But now looking at Chrome developer tools, Timeline tab with Loading box checked, I look at and got something along these lines:

```
Send Request (this is request for HTML page itself)
Receive data
Receive data
Receive data (this are pockets coming if I understand correctly)
Finish Loading (here page is loaded now)
Parse HTML (now browser starts reading actual HTML code)
Send Request (a.js)
```

Now, in here I would expect the browser to halt everything and wait till `a.js` will be fully downloaded, then executed and only then start parsing HTML further and reading `b.js` and the rest)
I have however this output further:

```
Send Request b.js (Why is this happening, a.js is not finished loading yet)
Send Request c.js (again why?)
Send Request d.css
```

Only then at some point I get:

```
Finish Loading a.js
```

Browser executes `a.js` and only then other files (if already downloaded) are executed in order of `SCRIPT` tags in html.

Now my question is how browser knows to request `b.js`, `c.js` and `css` file if the `a.js` wasn't fully downloaded and executed? Is Chrome applying some magick to optimise and speed up process? What if `a.js` when run modifies and removes the rest of `SCRIPT` tags? Is the request wasted then? Or am I simply reading output wrong?

Comment: Pretty simple, the browser downloads them async in parallel with everything else. It would be a waste to wait for one and one of them to complete.

Answer (score 1):

A: Because each of the JS files are specified in the HTML. The browser tries to batch-up as many downloads as it can to save time. From the moment you right-click on something and select "save link as" it's being downloaded - even though you haven't specified a file name yet. If you then hit cancel instead of specifying a name/location, you have wasted whatever was already downloaded.

Chrome applies a similar policy with regards to resources in a page. If a.js removes any/all subsequent script tags, then yes - their download has been in vain.

The alternative is to have choppy performance.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple things to download, browsers will normally download several of them in parallel. The exact number of parallel downloads can vary by browser.

Note: The CSS should be before the JS to get maximum benefit from parallel downloads.

Comment: yes, CSS styles may be needed by Scripts while they may want to manipulate dom.